# The camera adds ten pounds?

Tags: expressions

While trying to understand the term 'photogenic' better, I came across [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogenic#Two_eyes.2C_one_lens) which mentions the expression *'the camera adds ten pounds'*.

> With a camera, the subject is viewed through a single lens, and thus much of the three dimensional qualities of the face are lost, and the face may appear to be fuller than it actually is in real life(which is the reason for the expression that "the camera adds ten pounds")...

Does this expression refer to people looking 'bigger' in their photographs than they actually are or to refer to people looking 'better' in them? Since *adding pounds* usually refers to putting on weight, I would think the expression suggests that people look heavier in the photographs. But is that photogenic?

Comment: You've got it right; it means that you look roughly 10 pounds heavier depicted in two dimensions.

Comment: But is looking ten pounds heavier 'photogenic'?

Comment: Photogenic refers to how well you take pictures. For most people, adding 10 pounds would make them less photogenic, but, for someone who is very thin, it might have the opposite effect. I'm no expert on this matter, but I believe this is why so many models (or those trying to break into a career in modeling) can be so thin – sometimes dangerously so.

Comment: @J.R. - doesn't *photogenic* means how well a person looks in photographs in general rather than referring to his photo taking capabilities?!

Comment: @Mohit: Yes, and I'm using that expression to mean exactly what you say. "That person photographs well" can apply to either end of the camera - it can mean that person snaps good pictures (like photographer Ansel Adams) or it can mean that person looks good in pictures (like supermodel Gisele Bundchen). It's a phrasal use of the word, noted in [this dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/photograph_7).

Comment: Frankly, the phrase is essentially a white lie used to console people unhappy with their pictures.

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. The Wikipedia article clearly explains the [possibly, *supposed*] effect. It's entirely subjective whether any given person looks better or worse because of any such distortion, but obviously the most common context is *women* who are worried they look too fat - so people reassure them it's just a camera artefact.

Comment: You've just misunderstood the direction of the explanation in that paragraph. The "adds ten pounds" phenomenon is just an example of how one can seem different in a picture than in real life. And being photogenic is possibly different in a picture than in real life. Otherwise they are on opposite sides of the quality of the transformation of looks through pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The camera adds ten pounds" is just an expression which is used with regard to photographs. It doesn't always carry a negative connotation as it may seem at first instance. As mentioned by you in the question, it basically refers to the fact that people look heavier or bigger in photographs.

Now, is that a good thing or is that photogenic? It depends upon the eyes of the beholder.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered to be a bad thing. The expression seems to be used most often when a person dislikes how they look in a photograph or in a film, as a way to console them: "You're not really that large, the camera adds ten pounds."

Comment: But the article I have referred tries to explain what 'photogenic' is through the expression or at least that's how I've understood it.

Comment: @InglishTeeture I believe that parenthetical aside is unrelated to the topic of 'photogenic'. Wikipedia sometimes does that, unfortunately.

Comment: @InglishTeeture:  I believe the article is referring to the expression in terms of how it affects the photogenic nature of the subject.   Typically, the apparent adding of weight will have an adverse affect on the photogenic qualities of the subject, because most people (that I know anyway) don't want to look 10 pounds heavier than they really are.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's often taken in our culture that having more weight makes you less attractive, to be *photogenic* would mean either you weren't affected by the "adds then pounds" phenomenon, or if you were, that it didn't have much effect upon how attractive you were considered.